# find index of values containing keyword in array python

Tags: python, list

I want to find the index of values that contain a keyword in an array.

For example:

```
A = ['a1','b1','a324']
keyword = 'a'
```

I want to get `[0,2]`, which is the index of `a1, a324`

I tried this `list(filter(lambda x:'a' in x, A))`
But get `['a1','a324']` rather than the index.

Comment: `[i for i, e in enumerate(A) if keyword in e]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` with a list-comprehension:

```
A = ['a1','b1','a324']
keyword = 'a'

print([i for i, x in enumerate(A) if keyword in x])
# [0, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply write:

```
A = ['a1','b1','a324']
keyword = 'a'
indices = [i for i in range(len(A)) if keyword in A[i]]
print(indices)
```